# How to refresh webpage without changing the page index of gridview only once?

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, gridview

I've noticed that when i delete an item in my gridview, the page will postback and the item that i deleted is still visible in the gridview. But when i refresh the webpage that contains the gridview, the deleted item is no longer visible in the gridview.

So i decided that I need to do a Response.Redirect in my code so that the deleted item will no longer be visible. It did work fine but it always goes back to the first page index of the gridview. Currently i have 5 page index in my gridview. If I delete a data lets say in page index 5, the response.redirect will execute and then it will go back to page index 1. I need to go all the way back to page index 5 in order to check whether the data is deleted in my gridview or not, which is actually deleted.

Now I've found a piece of code online on how to stay on the same page index when the webpage is refreshed. The solution is Sessions. I've integrated the code with sessions but now here is the problem. It always stays in the last page index that you've been into. Lets say you are in page index 5 of your gridview and then you went to your home page, if you go back to the webpage that has the gridview, it would still be in page index 5.

What i want to happen is when i delete an item in gridview, it will refresh the webpage but the gridview page index would be on the last page index that your into only once so that the deleted item will no longer be visible. And finally when i decided to go to a different page(lets say a homepage or about page) and go back to the webpage that has the gridview, it should then be able to reset to the first index of the gridview. How to achieve this? I hope this makes sense to you guys.

Here is the code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack){
        bindgridviewguitaritems();

        if (Session["pageNumber"] != null)
        {
           GridViewIndexChanging(GuitarItemsGridView, new GridViewPageEventArgs((int)Session["pageNumber"]));
        }

    }
}

protected void GridViewIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
{
    GuitarItemsGridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
    Session["pageNumber"] = e.NewPageIndex;
    //whatever your page index changing does...
}

protected void GuitarItemsGridViewBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      Button btn = sender as Button;
      GridViewRow gridrow = btn.NamingContainer as GridViewRow;
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(GuitarItemsGridView.DataKeys[gridrow.RowIndex].Value.ToString());

    using (var context = new MusicStoreDBEntities())
    {
        var bay = (from s in context.stringInstrumentItems where s.itemId == id select s).FirstOrDefault();
        context.stringInstrumentItems.Remove(bay);
        context.SaveChanges();


    }

    bindgridviewguitaritems();
    Response.Redirect("~/Pages/OverviewGuitarData.aspx");
```

Comment: Just hide the deleted item on the front-end with JS and do an AJAX call to remove the record from the DB.

Comment: You can use an `UpdatePanel`. Delete the item from the database and rebind the grid with the updated data. The line will be gone and no (visible) page refresh is done.

Comment: Once delete the item you should do following. `var pageindex = GuitarItemsGridView.PageIndex; bindgridviewguitaritems(); GuitarItemsGridView.PageIndex = pageindex;` you don't need to use session .